# php parse_ini_file error parsing empty Line

Tags: php, parsing

I'm using parse_ini_file for a long time, but now it gives my a wired error.

> config.ini

```
[database]
host            = "xxx"
databasename    = xxx
user            = xxx
password        = xxx
typ             = xxx

[sql]
useragentsCountByClicksNoBots   = "SELECT ua.user_agent FROM clicks AS c JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id WHERE ua.is_bot = 0;"
useragentsCountByClicks         = "SELECT ua.user_agent FROM clicks AS c JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id;"

targetCountByClicksNoBots       = "SELECT t.url FROM clicks AS c JOIN target AS t ON t.id=c.target_id JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id WHERE ua.is_bot = 0;"
targetCountByClicks             = "SELECT t.url FROM clicks AS c JOIN target AS t ON t.id=t.target_id;"

[views]
Useragents[title]               = "Useragent"

Useragents[description]         = "Benutzte Browser in denen der Link    geklickt wurde"
Useragents[sql][bots]           = "SELECT ua.user_agent as name FROM clicks AS c JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id;"
Useragents[sql][noBots]         = "SELECT ua.user_agent as name FROM clicks AS c JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id WHERE ua.is_bot = 0;"

target[name]                    = "Target"
target[description]             = "Zielseite für den Link der geklickt wurde"
target[sql][bots]               = "SELECT t.url as name FROM clicks AS c JOIN target AS t ON t.id=c.target_id;"
target[sql][noBots]             = "SELECT t.url as name FROM clicks AS c JOIN target AS t ON t.id=c.target_id JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id WHERE ua.is_bot = 0;"

refferer[name]                  = "Refferer"
refferer[description]           = "Seiten auf denen der Link geklickt wurde"
refferer[sql][bots]             = "SELECT r.refferer as name FROM clicks AS c JOIN refferer AS r ON r.id=c.refferer_id;"
refferer[sql][noBots]           = "SELECT r.refferer as name FROM clicks AS c JOIN refferer AS r ON r.id=c.refferer_id JOIN user_agents AS ua ON ua.id=c.user_agent_id WHERE ua.is_bot = 0;"
```

> PHP Warning:  Error parsing ... on line 17 ...

But Like you see, Line 17 is empty.
What do i miss?

Comment: Try removing the empty line and create it again. Maybe some invisible unicode char thats messing up

Comment: I completly delete the parts starting with "Useragents" now the lines starting with "target" are there, but the same error stil in Line 17 comes up...

Comment: can you post full warning message, error parsing what, on line 17 where?

Comment: I only scipt the filepath and name. without path: [08-Jul-2015 11:38:16] PHP Warning:  Error parsing config.ini on line 17
 in class.pwDefaults.php on line 196

Comment: in class.pwDefaults.php there is the call for parse_ini_file like i use it in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

`parse_ini_file` does not support N-level multi-dimensional arrays in your ini files.

see [this answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#114842) from the php docs on how to implement this

Comment: On this Page in Example 1 they say it should work, but on my server it doesn't... anyway, thanks for the reply. I had made my own workaround. Maybe next times i read all comments on this page. :D